# Pseudo element content with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, pseudo-element

I am trying to change the arrow on an `:after` pseudo element

my css

```
legend:after {
    content: url('/html/img/arrow-fieldset-up.png');
}
```

I am trying to change with

```
$('legend', selected_fieldset).attr('content','url(/html/img/arrow-fieldset-down.png)')
```

Comment: Jquery can not do this. Why not to play with classes?

Comment: Pseudo elements aren't part of the DOM, so they can't be selected. There are some good workarounds here: **[Manipulating CSS pseudo-elements using jQuery (e.g. :before and :after)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-using-jquery-e-g-before-and-after)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot select the pseudo element with jQuery. Instead you can add a class to your CSS:

```
legend.selected:after {
    content: url('/html/img/arrow-fieldset-down.png');
}
```

then add this class when you want to change the content, for example when you click the legend:

```
$('legend').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
})
```